# If Statement that has two outcomes

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements, finance

I'm trying to define a new column ['Actual Loss'] that is dependent on the value of another column ['Loss']
If the value of ['Loss'] is less than zero then multiply it by -1
If the value of ['Loss'] is greater than zero then multiply it by 0

df1 = Investor, Loss

```
  Tom, -100
  Barry, 100
```

expected:

df1 = Investor, Loss, Actual Loss

```
  Tom, -100, 100
  Barry 100, 0
```

Code =
if len (df) < 0 :
df['Actual Loss'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Loss']*-1 if x['Loss'] <0 else x['Loss')*0)

Comment: `len(df)` cannot be smaller 0

Comment: IIUC, you need `np.where` i.e `np.where(df['actual'].lt(0), df['actual'].abs(), 0)` or something to that affect

Comment: got it using: df['Actual Loss'] = np.where(df['Loss'] <0, df['Loss']*-1, df['Loss']*0)

Comment: thank you for the help. much appreciated